# How to debug "Symbol not found" when loading mod_perl into xampp?

Tags: apache

`httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 13 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_perl.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/mod_perl.so, 10): Symbol not found: _modperl_handler_anon_add\n  Referenced from: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules/mod_perl.so\n  Expected in: dynamic lookup\`n

I couldn't open Apache when I using XAMPP, the issue keep showing up but I didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are currently simply expecting us to solve the problem **for you**. **PLEASE** Give it a try **on your own**, and then show us what you came up with - and if you get stuck along the way, feel free to come back and ask for help.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue after upgrading  - you can comment out the line   13 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: (with #) which will solve your problem initially, however you then won't be loading the pearl module which may or may not matter to you